# Hive query to assign grouped keys based on multiple optional keys

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hadoop2

We have a Hive table with three different IDs, all optional. In each row, at least one of the three IDs must be provided. If more than one ID is provided, this establishes an equivalence between the multiple IDs.

We need to assign a unique master ID to each row, based on equivalences established  in any row. For example:

```
Line   id1     id2     id3    masterID
--------------------------------------
(1)    A1                     M1
(2)            A2             M1
(3)                    A3     M1
(4)    A1      A2             M1
(5)            A2      A3     M1
(6)    B1      A2             M1
(7)    C1              C3     M2
```

Because on Line 4, both A1 and A2 are present, we know that these IDs are equivalent.

Likewise, on Line 5, both A2 and A3 are present, we know these IDs are also equivalent.

Again on Line 6, we have both B1 and A2, so these are also equivalent.

On line 7, we have an equivalence between C1 and C3.

Given the above information, A1, A2, A3 and B1 are all equivalent. Therefore, all rows containing any of these IDs must be assigned the same master ID, so we have given them all the same master ID ("M1"). Line 7 receives a unique ID all its own ("M2"), since neither of its IDs matches any other.

How can we write a Hive query to assign master IDs in this way? And if Hive is not the best tool to accomplish this, can you suggest a way to use some other tool in the Hadoop ecosystem to assign master IDs to these rows?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by representing your IDs as vertices and finding the connected components. More on the idea [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ukang/papers/PegasusKAIS.pdf), section 3.5. Let `init_table` is your table. First, build a link table

```
create table links as
select distinct id1 as v1, id2 as v2
  from init_table
 where id1 is not null and id2 is not null
union all 
select distinct id1 as v1, id3 as v2
  from init_table
 where id1 is not null and id3 is not null
union all 
select distinct id2 as v1, id3 as v2
  from init_table
 where id2 is not null and id3 is not null
;
```

Next generate some numbers for each link, for instance row number and perform propagation:

```
create table links1 as
with temp_table as (
  select v1, v2, row_number() over () as score
    from links
)
, tbl1 as (
  select v1, v2, score
       , max(score) over (partition by v1) as max_1
       , max(score) over (partition by v2) as max_2
    from temp_table
)
select v1, v2, greatest(max_1, max_2) as unique_id
  from tbl1
;
```

then just join you IDs with the matching table:

```
create table matching_table as
with temp_table as (
select v1 as id, unique_id
  from link1
union all
select v2 as id, unique_id
  from link1
)
select distinct id, unique_id
  from temp_table
```

If some IDs are not coupled then it's not hard to find out which ones.
Hope this helps.

Comment: The solution above seems promising, but it's easy to find scenarios for which it doesn't work. We tried adding clauses to cover the remaining undiscovered equivalences, but there were always more. I ended up writing a Java application to do this using  a combination of Maps and Sets. Performance is not too bad with a few million rows of coupled IDs.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you give me an example of such scenario? just to make sure I'm not missing something here as the connected components approach seems to be reasonable for this task.